# How do I define the controller for a partial view in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I define the controller for a partial view in rails? I don't know how to expand the question further.

Answer (score 1):

Any partial that I use between controllers is in the `layouts` directory.  To use the partial, I then use the following code:

```
render :partial => 'layouts/myPartial'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can just prepend to name of the partial:

In your view where you are using the partial:

```
render :partial => 'othercontroller/partialname'
```